# Why am I having a severe mouse lag when CPU usage spikes up to %100?

Tags: cpu, performance, mouse, lag

I'm having a very noticeable mouse lag when my CPU usage spikes up to %100 or between %90 and %100, this happens when I open a project in visual studio, or when building a project, or when rendering a gif, so different operations, same problem. The weird thing is it doesn't happen when I'm doing stress test with AIDA64. My specs are:

- **OS:** Windows 10 64 bit, build 1703
- **CPU**: Intel i7 7700k @4.8 GHZ
- **Ram:** Corsair 2x16 3000 MHZ
- **GPU:** Nvidia 1080TI

My cpu is overclocked but I don't think it causes this, because I had the same issue when I didn't overclock the CPU. All of my drivers are up to date and there is no unknown device in device manager, so how can I find what is causing this lag and fix it ?

Comment: In my experience, this is normal behaviour. I came to conclude that CPU is needed to make the mouse cursor move. Maybe your test only stresses parts of the CPU that are not involved in controlling mouse movement.

Comment: open cmd.exe as admin and run **wpr.exe -start CPU -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl** now try to capture the mouse hangs while the CPU is at 100%. Zip the ETL + NGENPDB folder, share the zip on OneDrive.

Comment: This smells vaguely like "[24 Cores and the Mouse Won't Move: Engineer Diagnoses Windows 10 Bug](https://slashdot.org/story/17/07/11/2055251)" that was just published last week.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I did but the generated ETL file is so large, I recorded for like 1 minute and it's 6GB.

Comment: compress it as 7z and only try to capture 30s to have smaller files

Comment: @magicandre1981 okey it became 400 mb after compression, you can download here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqrUQtH4kgCTvEWA66H9KERaJb3P

Comment: any update on your issue?

Answer (score 4):

To capture the CPU usage in Windows 10, open cmd.exe as admin and run `wpr.exe -start CPU -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl` and when you captured 30-60s of the lags press a key to stop the logging.

Now load the generated `C:\HighCPUUsage.etl` in [WPA.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer) (You need to install the [Windows Performance Toolkit from the Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)) by doing a double click on it.

Drag & drop the graph `CPU Usage (Sampled)` from the left side under `Computation` to the `Analysis pane`

[image]

and change the view to `DPC and ISR Usage`

[image]

[Configure and load debug symbols](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/loading-symbols) in WPA.exe and extand the stack of `ntoskrnl.exe` and under `ntoskrnl.exe!KiExecuteAllDpcs` I see calls of `sshid.sys` and other Microsoft Mouse/keyboard drivers. `sshid.sys` also seams to be a mouse/keyboard driver. so update the driver or use the default MS drivers which provide only basic features.

While executing DPCs the whole system is blocked and this could cause your lags.

Answer (score 4):

just sharing my experience as I searched multiple forums about this  topic.

For me, this definitively solved the issue : deactivating startup load of every instance of "RtkAudUService64.exe", until there is no more any instance of it in the Task Manager after reboot.

Comment: The same solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I just found out yesterday that Logitech G-Hub caused all my problems with laggy mouse, and stuttering mouse when running specific programs.

And according to the internet, Logitech Gaming Software is likely to cause the same problems.

I tried different polling rates and DPI's without fixing the problem.
but as soon as i closed G-Hub the problems went away.